# how many clock ticks have occurred between these values?

Tags: clock

If a 16 bit timer counter registers an event at 0xB123 and a subsequent event at 0x23B1 how many clock ticks have occurred between these values?

2^16 = 65536
0xB123 in decimal is 45347
0x23B1 in decimal is 9137

Not sure if I am correct. But do you just subtract 9137 from 45347 which gives the answer 36210?

Comment: `36210 + 65536*n` where `n` is the number of times that the register has wrapped-around.

Answer (score 1):

Lol, microcomputers 204 tutorial?

Since the question say a "subsequent event at 0x23B1"

Not sure if im correct either, but doesn't the counter overflows at 65536? So the max address should be 65535, hence 65535-45347=20188 (before it reaches overflow to start at 0 again.) then plus 9137 (20188+9137=29325?)

What do you think?

Comment: no idea. but you have a 'tick' next to your answer. so i guess youre correct?